# ASP.NET Core MapFallbackToFile is not handling non-existings urls. Only homepage

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, blazor, fallback

I am creating Blazor app. If I navigate to homepage - page loads fine, then I navigate into article e.g. `localhost/new-article`. Next step is page refresh via F5. Page returns 404 not found. My fallback is not picking it up.

Startup.cs

```
endpoints.MapBlazorHub(blazorOptions =>
{
   blazorOptions.ApplicationMaxBufferSize = blazorOptions.TransportMaxBufferSize = 20 * 1024 * 1024;
});
endpoints.MapRazorPages();
endpoints.MapControllers();
endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/_Host");
```

Fallback should take `localhost/new-article` however I dont know why its not.

**_Host.cshtml** first line

```
@page "/"
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue here is that you need to swap MapFallbackToFile to MapFallbackToPage.